# Python and regex to find a number of length 5

Tags: python, regex

So currently I've got the string

```
'JavaScript:doEdit('41228', '', '', 2);'
```

I'd like to do regex in python on it to filter out ONLY the 41228. I've tried two methods and came up with issues on both. The first was trying to find things that aren't digits of length 5 by using

```
re.sub('^\d{5}', string )
```

Then I tried re.match and re.compile which gives me the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'.

The only thing close I've done is use re.sub{'\D', string} but then it sticks in the extra 2 I don't want.

I guess it wouldn't be an issue to just find the 19th through 24th characters in the string. since the string should never change composition. When I generate a new id.

SOLVED: working code is

```
screen_id = 'JavaScript:doEdit('41228', '', '', 2);'
reduced_screenc_id = re.search(r'\d{5}', screenc_id)
print (reduced_screenc_id.group())
```

Comment: The `^` makes the pattern match at the start of the string only.

Comment: Haha. I figured that out. That's why i'm here asking what to do.

Comment: You may use `re.search(r"'(\d+)'", s)` (if `s` is a string) and grab the `group(1)` value. Or split with `'` and get the second item. See https://ideone.com/HMyRcw

Comment: It also looks like you passed in an integer as replacement, not a string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew using the .group() method worked fantastic off the re.search()

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.findall` to find all (non-overlapping) instances of the pattern in your string:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "JavaScript:doEdit('41228', '', '', 2);"
>>> pattern = '\d{5}'  # 5 digits
>>> number = re.findall(pattern, string)[0]
>>> number
'41228'
```

You might want to cast the "number" to an actual number using `number = int(number)` then.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is always in this format, you may use a mere split operation with `'`:

```
s = "JavaScript:doEdit('41228', '', '', 2);"
print(s.split("'")[1])
# => 41228
```

If you plan to study  regex, you may use `re.search` with either `\d{5}` or `doEdit'(\d{5})'` regex.

```
import re
s = "JavaScript:doEdit('41228', '', '', 2);"
res = re.search(r"\d{5}", s)
if res:
    print(res.group())    # Here, we need the whole match
res = re.search(r"doEdit\('(\d{5})'", s)
if res:
    print(res.group(1)) # Grabbing Group 1 value only
```

Since you need only the first match, there is no point using `re.findall`.

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/nF5SAL).